# What is the best word to describe a person's false pride?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I need to build up a sentence saying like this "She has no false pride like other actresses, she replies to every message sent by her fans". I need to emphasize that she has no false pride like other actresses. Much appreciated if someone can build a better sentence than mine. thanks.

Comment: _False_ pride suggests the subject isn't actually proud. Is that what you're hoping to convey?

Comment: a celeb is trying to be special and highlighted among people while he/she can be normal with people like some celebs do. that's what I meant.

Comment: You could go the other way, and say, *Unlike other actresses she's very down to earth and approachable- she replies to every message sent by her fans.*

Comment: Aha, there you go, short and sweet. appreciated.

Comment: Not replying to her fans may be a case of *arrogance* rather than egotism.

Answer (score 5):

Celebrities are sometimes

[egotistical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egotistical): characteristic of those having an *inflated idea of their own importance*; A *conceited*, boastful person.

[conceited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conceited): having a high or exaggerated opinion of oneself or one's accomplishments; *vain*

or [smug](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smug): contentedly confident of one's ability, superiority, or correctness; complacent.

or [snobbish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snobbish) - befitting or characteristic of those who incline to social exclusiveness and who rebuff the advances of people considered inferior

(TFD)

Comment: Egostical, that suits well I think.

Comment: Got it. yes, it can be used interchangeably. very helpful

Comment: Also "self-important" and "aloof" fit the context

Answer (score 4):

I think [conceit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Conceit) or vanity, may convey the idea:

> - a high, often exaggerated, opinion of oneself or one's accomplishments, [vanity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vanity).

Source: /www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Yes, I think conceit will do, but still confused how to build up the sentence though.

Comment: That is great, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**hubris** - defined by Google dictionary as: excessive pride or self-confidence, and in Greek tragedy an excessive pride toward or defiance of the gods, leading to nemesis.

So there is a hint with this word that such pride will lead to a humilating fall in time.

Comment: I wouldn't use hubris, though, unless you wanted to strongly suggest a coming nemesis. (Which you're right, the OP might want to do!).